# power module multiple voltage SMD

Tags: arduino, power, mosfet

I want to build a power module with a MOSFET (for an Arduino MEGA) and with multiple voltages (5, 12, 24 VDC) on each output (with jumper or micro-switch). I want protect the card with an octocoupler and diodes on outputs; also I want use 32 outputs (PWM), so, for reduce the size of the power board, I think use SMD components.

Now, is it possible to make this, and what components  will I use to realize it ?

Comment: your English is pretty OK, so I just reduced your text to your question and eliminated the distraction. Anyway, what is "CMS"? It might be a French abbreviation, but these usually don't translate overly well to English, so maybe you could look CMS up in the French Wikipedia, and click on the English version of that side to find the right acronym?

Comment: Yes sorry, CMS is French abbrevation, i forger it. Is "composants montés en surface", in english, i presume is SMD.

Comment: I edited (CMS = french for SMD). Need to know how much current the outputs should deliver, into what loads, and if output voltage should be software selectable or set in hardware (for example via jumpers). Will you have external 5-12-24 supplies? Or put a few DC-DC on your board. And.... why not open drain outputs which are voltage-agnostic?

Comment: So you want to built a 32 channel power supply with selectable outputs, and you don't know which components to use? Sounds like there's a lot of learning. _Too broad_ if I ever saw one! You're basically asking for the complete design here.

Comment: I think the power ouptut can be between 5 and 10A maxi. Is for led strip (5 meters maxi) and 3W rgb led. Also for a small motor.

Comment: pipe you'r right, i have post here because i not find this cars everywhere. I have a little skill on electronic but not enought for this board.

Answer (score 2):

I will go with a solution that won't be optimal according to most, but that I believe has a better chance of working best for you.

Since the revolution of $20 double sided PCBs delivered in a pack of 10 to your door via internet, the way costs should be calculated for a one-off amateur project has changed. For example, a very large PCB with many outputs will be expensive. However, for $20 you can get 10 identical PCBs.

Since you have high current LED strips, I presume you have the corresponding power supplies. I advise against embarking in the design of DC-DC converters for your project: buy pre-made supplies, it's much simpler.

So, this is what I would do:

Build modules, small PCBs... for example, a module with 3 MOSFETs and associated circuits which will control a RGB LED strip, or 3 LED strips. Smaller is easier to debug. Also, on each PCB you can put different components to make variants, which is flexible.

Cutting a large board into separate modules increases probability of success. A large board has higher probability of errors.

Power these modules from your power supplies.

Now, to control these modules. You will need a PWM IC. This could be a SPI-controllable chip, or a super cheap chinese arduino clone... or even an ESP8266, your choice. I would put opto-isolators on each, if wired transmission is used.

I'm being very vague on purpose. This was too long for a comment. So, think this over, be more specific in your requirements, and we'll see.

Comment: Not a bad way to approach this..

Comment: actually, cheap esp8266 would solve lots of problems if OP is willing to hack some tcp/ip code... I mean, no-one likes wires running all over the place! that depends if it'll be in his home (then wifi is OK) or somewhere like on stage (where you really dont want the show to blow up because wifi barfs up)

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the reply. I have already different power supplies, one 5/12 VDC and one 24 VDC. I just want a mosfet board because Arduino is to limited for powered my project.